# Notification Huawei EMUI

Tags: android, notifications, huawei-mobile-services

Iam writing notification app. To set notification i use AlarmManager.

All seems to working well, unfortunately not in Huawei.
When user close app notifications not comming (on other devices LG,NEXUS all is working well).

Any idea how to fix it?

```
    intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, intent, 0);


    am.set(android.app.AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeToAlarm, sender);
```

## EDIT

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG = "AlarmReceiver";
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);

    wakeLock.acquire();

    new NotificationUtils(context, null).postNotification(context.getString(R.string.notification_title), context.getString(R.string.notification_message));

    unlock();
}

private void unlock() {
    if (wakeLock != null)
        if (wakeLock.isHeld())
            wakeLock.release();

    wakeLock = null;
}
```

}

Comment: you said that you close your app. Ok but there is a service or a broadcast receiver in background? If you close app android can kill it.

Comment: I just swipe it out from process list. Is it possible that only on this type of devices, after it it kill all broadcasts? and if is, what can i do to prevent it?

Comment: you cannot rely in your app to launch notification because it can be cancelled at any moment. You shoudl implement a broadcastreceiver or a service in background and launch notification from it. In other phone works but is random.

Comment: As u can see i already have registered AlarmReceiver 
        <receiver android:name=".receivers.AlarmReceiver"/>

Comment: oh ok, if that http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/152649/what-is-protected-apps-in-huawei-phones doesn't work is weird :\

Answer (score 0):

There is Protected apps option in settings. Go there and select your application

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution while testing my notifications.
After writing this call ifHuaweiAlert() in OnCreate() and see what happens.

```
private void ifHuaweiAlert() {
    final SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ProtectedApps", MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String saveIfSkip = "skipProtectedAppsMessage";
    boolean skipMessage = settings.getBoolean(saveIfSkip, false);
    if (!skipMessage) {
        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClassName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity");
        if (isCallable(intent)) {
            final AppCompatCheckBox dontShowAgain = new AppCompatCheckBox(this);
            dontShowAgain.setText("Do not show again");
            dontShowAgain.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    editor.putBoolean(saveIfSkip, isChecked);
                    editor.apply();
                }
            });

            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle(R.string.huawei_protected_apps)
                    .setMessage(String.format("%s" + " "requiers to be enabled in Protected Apps) , getString(R.string.app_name)))
                    .setView(dontShowAgain)
                    .setPositiveButton("Protected Apps", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            huaweiProtectedApps();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null)
                    .show();
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean(saveIfSkip, true);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }
}

private boolean isCallable(Intent intent) {
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    return list.size() > 0;
}

private void huaweiProtectedApps() {
    try {
        String cmd = "am start -n com.huawei.systemmanager/.optimize.process.ProtectActivity";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            cmd += " --user " + getUserSerial();
        }
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
}

private String getUserSerial() {
    //noinspection ResourceType
    Object userManager = getSystemService("user");
    if (null == userManager) return "";

    try {
        Method myUserHandleMethod = android.os.Process.class.getMethod("myUserHandle", (Class<?>[]) null);
        Object myUserHandle = myUserHandleMethod.invoke(android.os.Process.class, (Object[]) null);
        Method getSerialNumberForUser = userManager.getClass().getMethod("getSerialNumberForUser", myUserHandle.getClass());
        Long userSerial = (Long) getSerialNumberForUser.invoke(userManager, myUserHandle);
        if (userSerial != null) {
            return String.valueOf(userSerial);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | IllegalAccessException ignored) {
    }
    return "";
}
```